# Second order linear differential equation non homogenuous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the differential equation: $y''+4y=3xcos(2x)$

The complementary solution is $y_c = C_1cos(2x)+C_2sin(2x)$

I am to set up a particular solution. $y_p = (Ax+B)(Ccos(2x)+Dsin(2x)$

Clearly there is duplication of $cos(2x)$ so I have to multiply everything by x

$y_p= x(Ax+B)(Ccos(2x)+Dsin(2x))$

foiling: $x(Ax+B)= Ax^2+Bx$

foiling: $Ax^2+Bx(Ccos(2x)+Dsin(2x)) = Ax^2Ccos(2x)+Ax^2Dsin(2x)+BxCcos(2x)+BxDsin(2x)$

for a final answer of: $Ax^2Ccos(2x)+Ax^2Dsin(2x)+BxCcos(2x)+BxDsin(2x)$

But the answer in the book is: $y_p= Axcos(2x)+Bxsin(2x)+Cx^2cos(2x)+Dx^2sin(2x)$

I am unsure of where I went wrong

Comment: Maybe you mean $y''$ and not $y^2$

Comment: Okay yes my mistake

Comment: @BlackKnightRider Why do you think your answer is different from the solution? There is no point in keeping products of arbitrary constants...

Comment: Both solutions are the same. The book 's guess is simply more simple. Both guess have four constants.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same. Call $BC=A_{book}$, $BD=B_{book}$, $AC=C_{book}$, and $AD=D_{book}$

Comment: Okay that makes sense

Comment: Try not to multiply two parameters (make up a new parameter name for that)